# Please help me to show selected image at invoice pdf same as logo

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

[image]I have created text fields and show their text at invoice and it's working fine. Now i want to show chosen picture also, but it is not working.

Comment: Have you even tried to look for it?

Comment: Yes, i have tried. I recently add a text field in the same directory. Actually now i want to add Choose file button exactly like the on for choose image for pdf invoice logo. please tell me how to do it. @JulienLachal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As name suggest module name is sales and it is in system so in etc folder system.xml**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/system.xml
```

add below code

```
<logo_invoice translate="label comment">
                            <label>Logo for PDF Invoice Print-outs (200x50)</label>
                            <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image_pdf</backend_model>
                            <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">sales/store/logo_invoice</upload_dir>
                            <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">sales/store/logo_invoice</base_url>
                            <sort_order>101</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment><![CDATA[Default logo, will be used in PDF and HTML documents.<br />(jpeg, tiff, png) If you see image distortion in PDF, try to use larger image]]></comment>
                        </logo_invoice>
```

use **logo_invoice**

```
$image = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/newgroups/logo_invoice'); $page->drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
```

Comment: @AliZaki find updated answer for your requirement

Comment: I did that, and button is showing now. but i want to show chosen image at invoice like logo. I am using this  $image = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/newgroups/logo');
        $page->drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2); but it is not working. kindly help me.

Comment: Lately i have added a text filed at same directory and it is working fine. I'm showing text by using         $text = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/newgroup/put_custom_text');              $page->drawText($text, 15, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');. It is showing on pdf correctly and now i want to show image also.

Comment: find updated answer and update your question @AliZaki

Comment: It's not working Sir. As i told you i have done the same before but it is not working. I think that something is wrong with  <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">sales/store/logo_invoice</base_url>. Once i choose image and save config, ah again image is gone it is not saved at admin panel too.

Comment: its working at my side and also creates new directory in media/sales/store ans shows image in admin @AliZaki Just check you are using code properly ...  `<upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">sales/store/logo_invoice</upload_dir>
                            <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">sales/store/logo_invoice</base_url>`

Comment: Please take a look at edited question. New field of choose file is not working.

Comment: It's working bro. It creates new directory also. Thank you so much. Now i am doing something wrong in this--->>> $image = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/identity/logo', $store);
        if ($image) {
            $image = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/sales/store/logo_invoice/' . $image;
            if (is_file($image)) {
                $image       = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($image);
                $page->drawImage($image, 10, 10, 200, 200);
                $this->y = $y1 - 0;
            }
        }.

Comment: when i give it the path-------->>> $image = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;,--- it shows the logo image. but when i give the path of new image -->>>>>$image = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/sales/store/logo_invoice/' . ---$image; it shows nothing. please solve it too.

Comment: if you find this helpful thn mark it as accept so it can be helpful to other @AliZaki

Comment: of course that was helpful. And please solve the last problem also.

Comment: @AliZaki upps sry but will you please explain it properly

Comment: `$image = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/identity/logo', $store);             $image = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;                      $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($image);                                         $page->drawImage($image, 10, 10, 200, 200);`
this code is showing image correctly that is inside the media/sales/store/logo. But when i do media/sales/store/logo_invoice nothing is showing.

Comment: `<upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">sales/store/logo_invoice</upload_dir>
                            <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">sales/store/logo_invoice</base_url>` is this showing uploaded image in admin? @AliZaki

Comment: It's done. now its working fine.`$image = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/identity/logo', $store); ` i was using the tags path of logo image. i should use from my module . now its done. thank you so much

Comment: @AliZaki welcome and mark it as accepted it will be helpful to close question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find it under

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/system.xml
```

and then you should be able to modify it if needed. 
As of my knowledge here it is also not necessary to create a copy in local so if you want new fields or modify these the best way in my opinion would be to create an extra module for that.